# Which algorithm is used by Garbage Collector

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

In one of the interview, interviewer asked me the name of algorithm used by Garbage collection in .NET for memory cleanup.
Can some one suggest me the name?
Please not that i am aware of how it is done(managed code..GCRoots..Generations..etc).

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422918/how-does-garbage-collection-and-scoping-work-in-c
I think tylerl's answer is the one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Idos.

Name of algorithm is "mark-and-sweep algorithm". I guess this is what interviewer wanted to know.
It is very well descirbed at:
[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/01/30/back-to-basics-mark-and-sweep-garbage-collection.aspx)